# Looping through an R vector to apply a formula

Tags: r

I am trying to loop through two vectors and apply a formula to the data but I can't figure out how to do what I want to do...

Basically here is some sample data...two vectors that I need to reference...

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
v2 <- c(0.01,0.06,0.11,0.16,0.21,0.26,0.31,0.36,0.41,0.46,0.51,0.56,0.61,0.66,0.71,0.76,0.81)
```

This is this the formaula I would like to apply...this would be the first instance...

```
(1+v2[2])^v1[2] / (1+(v2[1]^v1[1]))
```

The second iteration would be...

```
(1+v2[3])^v1[3] / (1+(v2[2]^v1[2]))
```

So I am trying to do this but I can't figure out how to iterate the vector index...I am trying along the lines of this but I can't increase the index via a counter, e.g., i...

```
for (i in seq_along(v1) {
    i <- 0
    res[i] <- ((1+v2[2+i])^v1[2+i] / (1+(v2[1+i]^v1[1+i]))
    i <- i+1
}
```

After going through the loop I would get the following output...

```
> res
 [1] 1.112475 1.217187 1.323924 1.432501 1.542753 1.654534 1.767715 1.882178 1.997821 2.114550 2.232280 2.350938 2.470454 2.590767 2.711821 2.833564
```

I have done lots of searching but I am coming up blank, any suggestions?

Comment: why are you changing `i` inside the loop?

Comment: I was trying to iterate the vector index.

Comment: `i in seq_along(v1)` this will iterate over vector indices. And you are initializing `i <- 0` inside the loop. So your i will always be zero, when you are evaluating the formula. On another note indices in R start at 1 and not 0.

Comment: Thanks. I will try play around with what you suggest. Yes, that is is good point in the i <- 0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one go with `res <- (1+v2[-1])^v1[-1] / (1+(v2[-17]^v1[-17]))`

Basically this uses length-16 vectors (v1 and v2 minus the first and last elements) and takes advantage of R's natural vector processing.

Comment: That is an elegant solution! Much simpler than I was trying to do! Thanks.